# Minimization values for a function

Tags: c++, python, c

I have got function - non linear(I thk), and a set of variable

`S=[(x1,y1),(x2,y2)...]`.

The objective is to find the value for `x` and `y` such that

`sum of( max(|x-xi|,|y-yi|) for each (xi,yi) element of S is minimized and | | represents absolute value`.

I came across a function `optimize()` in **python** but I don't really know if that works for this case. Is there any algorithm I can code myself to find the solution i.e x and y.

```
eg : S=[(1,4),(2,3),(0,1),(1,1)]

for x=1.5 and y=2.5(and some other values as well) the function gives the minimum value : 5
max(|1.5-1|,|2.5-4|)=1.5
max(|1.5-2|,|2.5-3|)=0.5
max(|1.5-0|,|2.5-1|)=1.5
max(|1.5-1|,|2.5-1|)=1.5
sum:5.0
```

Comment: Please make it clear whether `S` is a dictionary or a list.

Comment: this sounds like a simple regression problem, though you are minimizing straight residuals instead of squared residuals.  I would use basic algebra/calculus to minimize the objective function rather than hack something together to brute force it.

Comment: @Xaranke it is a `set` of tuples, as he said and showed.

Comment: @roippi As far as I know, the curly braces are used for dictionaries.

Comment: @Xaranke expand your understanding.

Comment: @roippi: representation doesn't matter..take it as a list or a set of tuples

Comment: @roippi: Sorry my mind could only figure out a brute force algorithm. can you please tell something more about the algebraic/calculus technique you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

if ‘{’  can be replaced by '[',it will be much easier to understand.It means a list store tuples.your purpose is to find the minimum in (|x-xi|,|y-yi|) and sum the minimum ? If i do not misunderstand your purpose,we can do like this:
assume x=5 y=5
sum=0
for elem in s:
  sum = sum+(abs(5-elem[0])>abs(5-elem[1]) and abs(5-elem[1]) and abs(5-elem[0]))

this is what you want ?

Comment: maybe you have to change it back.i want to use python to fulfil Binary Operator like C.you'd better google it.